# Whats the replacement for @Scripts.Render in MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, d3.js, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to run some d3js on my MVC 6 and was looking at this example https://github.com/DustinEwers/D3-DotNetMVC-Demos/blob/master/D3Demos/Views/TagDemos/BasicBarChart.cshtml and it uses

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/d3")
@section Scripts{
```

But if I do that I get

> The name 'Scripts' does not exist in the current context

So is there a new way to do it in MVC 6 ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In ASP.NET 5, There is no such `Scripts.Render` method. To render scripts, you may use the environment tag helper.

It is not necessary that you should use the environment tag helper. You can directly put your script tags in the layout file. But the environment helpers allows us to conditionally render scripts based on the environment. (*Minified-Bundled version vs All Un minified version*)

Here is the syntax, you can include this in your Layout file.

```html
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/d3.js"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery">
    </script>            
    <script src="~/js/d3.min.js" asp-file-version="true"></script>
</environment>
```

Assuming you have the script files `d3.js` `and d3.min.js` exist in `~/js` directory.

Also you need to make sure that you  have invoked the `UseStaticFiles()` method inside the `Configure()` method(inside *Startup.cs*)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,  
                                                             ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     //Other configuration goes here
     app.UseStaticFiles();  // This enables static file serving from the app.
     app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
}
```

`UseStaticFiles()` extension method enables static file serving including js files,css files etc..

When you run the application in Development mode, It will render the script tags inside  environment `"Development"` and when you run it in either Staging or Production, It will render script tags under the `"Staging,Production"` environment.

You can change the environment value by right clicking on the project and select `properties->Debug` and specify the value of the environment variable `Hosting:Environment`

You can see that i have included the minified version of js files in the Staging/Production enviornment. This is not necessary but preferred approach as it will save some bandwidth. (*You can put the un-minified version also there instead of minified if you really want to do that.*). If you have a single bundled file, you may use that also here instead of individual files.

If you already do not have a minified version, you can generate that by running the gulp task for minification.(This is included in the default `gulp.js` file which is in the new web app template). You just need to open up the task runner and run the minification task.

[image]

If you do not wish to manually run this every time, You may select `Bindings -> Before build` so that this will automatically run that purticular gulp task everytime you build your project.

Comment: Awesome answer btw :)

Comment: It seems like Microsoft has moved away from Gulp, at least by default. The template projects now rely on the `BundlerMinifier.Core` tool, as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc

Answer (score 7):

It's a bit more complicated now, but the [documentation](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingfrommvc5.html#configure-bundling) explains it quite well:

> The ASP.NET MVC 5 starter web template utilized ASP.NET’s built-in support for bundling. In ASP.NET MVC 6, this functionality is better performed using client build steps...

So to bundle scripts together you can use a tool like `gulp-concat`. And to include a script, just add it in the way you would if it were static content:

```html
<script src="~/lib/bundle.js"></script>
```

For a more complete example of including content, the answer by @Shyju is excellent.

Comment: It absolutely does not answer how to include minified files into view automatically! As I see it for now we have to specify each file separately.

Answer (score 1):

If you just wan't to run that script, simply create a html script tag:

```html
<script src="js/d3.js?version=1"></script>
```

But i really recommend that you bundle and minify your asset files.
You can bundle, minify, move (and a lot more) your javascript/css files with the help of taskrunners like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and Grunt.

Information on how to use gulp can be found here: http://rudiv.se/Article/asp-net-5-bundling-with-bower-and-gulp

And then with the help of Shyju post load correct files when you run your development or staging environment.

Comment: Don't use URL shorteners, they are just another link in a chain that can break.