# @Styles.Render() in .Net Core: The name 'Styles' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm converting ASP.NET MVC projects to ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 version.

I have mentioned the style paths in `bundleconfig.json` file. But how can we render these in ASP.Net Core cshtml files as we do in ASP.Net MVC like below:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/UserAdmin")
```

When I try to use the same in .Net Core, I'm getting this error:

> The name 'Styles' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use "Scripts" and "Styles" in ASP.NET Core which originates from Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization (.net-framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56806595/use-scripts-and-styles-in-asp-net-core-which-originates-from-microsoft-aspne)